# Removing vectors containing only zero in a list of lists of numerical vectors

Tags: r

I have an object of this structure:

```
l1 <- list(A=(list(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(1,4,5), z=c(1,2,3))),
           B=(list(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(1,4,5), z=c(1,2,3))),
           D=(list(a=c(0,0,0), b=c(0,0,0), z=c(0,0,0))))
```

I would like to remove any lists within `l1`, which contains only zeroes, in this case `l1["D"]`. I tried solutions with x!=0 within lapply, but failed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
Filter(length, lapply(l1, function(x) Filter(function(y) !all(y ==0), x)))
```

---

Or with `discard`

```
library(purrr)
discard(l1, ~ all(unlist(.x) == 0) )
#$A
#$A$a
#[1] 1 2 3

#$A$b
#[1] 1 4 5

#$A$z
#[1] 1 2 3


#$B
#$B$a
#[1] 1 2 3

#$B$b
#[1] 1 4 5

#$B$z
#[1] 1 2 3
```

or with `keep`

```
keep(l1, ~ any(unlist(.x) != 0))
```

Comment: But this will also remove any sublist that contains zeros only. So, if A$z = c(0,0,0), it will also be removed, even if other A lists are non-zero

Comment: from original `l1`: `l1$A$z = c(0,0,0)`. And running your code will remove `l1$A$z`. While question makes it seem like that all sublists should be zero to be removed. So remove `l1$A` only if `l1$A$a` , `l1$A$b` , `l1$A$z`  all are zero. (I assumed it from example of `l1["D"]` in original post)

Comment: all solutions work, accepting this for being the first answer. many thanks to and an upvote for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `sapply`

```
l1[!sapply(l1, function(x) all(unlist(x) == 0))]

#$A
#$A$a
#[1] 1 2 3

#$A$b
#[1] 1 4 5

#$A$z
#[1] 1 2 3


#$B
#$B$a
#[1] 1 2 3

#$B$b
#[1] 1 4 5

#$B$z
#[1] 1 2 3
```

---

Some `purrr` variation

```
library(purrr)
l1[map_lgl(l1, ~ !all(flatten_dbl(.) == 0))]
```

OR `keep`

```
keep(l1, ~ !all(flatten_dbl(.) == 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Filter`:

```
Filter(function(x) any(unlist(x) != 0), l1)
```